# How to find zeroes after given integer?

Tags: c++, string, int

Intro: I am making a program in C++ where I have to find level number of header tags in given some html code and print string(between starting and ending tag) after number. I have been able to do all parts except writing output in the format that is required.

**So the the question is how to remove zeroes after any integer assuming that you do not how many zeroes it has at the end**

For example:

**My output**

100000 : hi

210000 : hello

101000 : this

200000 : that

312000 : end

**Correct output:**

1: hi

2.1: hello

1.0.1: this

2: that

3.1.2: end

Can anyone tell me how to remove those zeroes after those numbers and put period between each numbers?

Comment: Hint: if the number is stored as (say) `int n`, you can get the last digit with `(n % 10)`, and you can chop off the last digit by dividing by 10.

Comment: Is this line structure consistent?  number(space):(space)word

Comment: @jason yes line structure is consistent and has only 6 digit number. I can later make those number in that format by putting dots in between but right now I am stuck in removing those zeroes at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not the most efficient, but it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string remzero_adddot(int x) {
    while(x%10==0)
        x /= 10;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << x%10;
    x /= 10;
    while(x) {
        ss << "." << x%10;
        x/=10;
    }
    string result = ss.str();
    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

int main() {
    cout << remzero_adddot(100000) << endl;
    cout << remzero_adddot(210000) << endl;
    cout << remzero_adddot(101000) << endl;
    cout << remzero_adddot(200000) << endl;
    cout << remzero_adddot(312000) << endl;
}
```